# How are compressor blades connected to the shaft in turbojet engines?

Tags: jet-engine

The below figure is about rotor and stator blades of compressor . How these are connected to the compressor shaft in jet engines ?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Could you edit your question to ask only one specific question per post? If you have multiple question you should ask them separately. It would be a good idea if you took our site [tour] and checked the [help] to see how the site works.

Comment: You’re asking about rotor blades. Why not specify the compressor rotor? People may think you’re enquiring after a helicopter rotor.

Comment: I would suggest reversing the terms to read "how are compressor blades connected to the rotor?"  I think that is more correct, and might clear up some some confusion.

Answer (score 5):

There are three primary ways that blades are connected to the shaft

1. **Circumferential dovetails**  Here is a nice site demonstrating it.  Includes STL files so you can 3D print your own demonstration part.
   https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/tool/jet-engine-component-1-1-axial-compressor-circumferential-dovetail-slot-type
2. **Axial dovetails** Here is a video demonstrating blades with an axial dovetail being assembled.  This particular video is a turbine, not a compressor, but in theory the same method can be used.
3. **Blisk** "Blisk" is a contraction of "bladed disk". The blades and the disk are physically welded together (or in some cases machined as one piece out of a solid block of metal).  Here's a wikipedia article on blisks
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blisk

Each of these methods has advantages and disadvantages in terms of weight, cost, vibration, etc.  Which one is picked depends on the circumstances.  It is also common to see multiple different methods within one compressor. For example the LEAP-1A HPC has a 10 stage compressor.  The forward stages are blisks, and the aft stages are circumferntial dovetails.